# How to eliminate angle parts of triangle to get six sided polygon with mask in Photoshop CS 5 or 6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, mask

I'm trying to recreate this image [image] with help of a Rectangle Tool `(U)` and masks as it was suggested in chat room, but so far I was able to do it by adding three rectangles, where two of them were turned a bit for lower cuts. Still due to stroke on main triangle I was unable to get exactly same shape as on image above.

Could anyone provide maybe an article or link to a tutorial.

**PS.** Obviously I could just cut those parts off. I'm more interested in masks usage to achieve that.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in chat, I'd normally do something like this:

- Create triangle (3 sided polygon, in Photoshop)
- Give triangle a stroke
- Create masks for corners (bottom ones 45 degrees to each side, you can hold Ctrl to make them rotate in intervals. masks in red in the image)

[image]

But looking at it again, you could actually use **another triangle mask** to get the same result. This would give you a very precise cut:

- Create triangle
- Give triangle a stroke
- Create another triangle on top of it, centered
- Use second triangle as mask

[image]

About how to use the mask, the quickest way I've found is to do the following:

- Create the triangle with the border and convert it to a Smart Object (this is so you don't have more than one mask for the same shape at the same time).
- Create the new triangle you want to use as mask and position it **below** the first one in the layers panel
- You will notice that your second triangle is basically a mask by itself - it's a color background, masked with a *triangle*. All you need to do is **drag** that mask into your first triangle.

The layers in this image are: 1) The original triangle turned into a Smart Object, 2) the new black triangle with its own mask that gives it the shape, and 3) The result when you drag your triangle 2 mask to triangle 1.

[image]

Comment: CS2!? Is that the one they used to design posters in WW2? :P

Comment: @Yisela here is link to what I have https://www.dropbox.com/s/q81qe6j5rx6a6ez/road-sign.psd. CC? You mean Adobe Creative Cloud?

Comment: @Eugene Sorry for the delay! Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zf6pldeql5x9t6t/road-sign.psd It took me a while to figure out how to move the mask in CC, but it's quite the same I had done in CS2. You create a new triangle with a mask, and then move the mask to the first one. I left the steps as invisible layers so you can see them.